# Setting Direct2D Matrix Effect Parameter

Tags: effect, direct2d

I play with some Effects of the Microsoft Direct2D and I see that
one parameter of the Matrix-Effect does not work as expected.
It ist the D2D1_CONVOLVEMATRIX_PROP_DIVISOR.
Nothing is changing when setting different values.
Has enybody expirience with that?

ID2D1Effect* theEffect = nullptr;

```
  m_pDeviceContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1ConvolveMatrix, &theEffect);

  float matrix[9] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1};
  theEffect->SetValue(D2D1_CONVOLVEMATRIX_PROP_KERNEL_SIZE_X,3);
  theEffect->SetValue(D2D1_CONVOLVEMATRIX_PROP_KERNEL_SIZE_Y,3);
  theEffect->SetValue(D2D1_CONVOLVEMATRIX_PROP_KERNEL_MATRIX, matrix);
  
  // this has no effect
  theEffect->SetValue(D2D1_CONVOLVEMATRIX_PROP_DIVISOR, 2.0);
```

Comment: Have you checked the HRESULT value from the `SetValue` calls? Also you must send unsigned int 32 for `D2D1_CONVOLVEMATRIX_PROP_KERNEL_SIZE_X` and float for `D2D1_CONVOLVEMATRIX_PROP_DIVISOR`. Depending on your language, you may be sending ints or doubles

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have checked the results. They are always S_OK.

Comment: Have you checked the values you pass are of the expected type?

Comment: Thank You very much. I thought it would be clear that 2.0 is float type.
But it seems that ist not. I made a explizid typecast to float an now it works.

Comment: 2.0 is "floating point", but float and double are different (32-bit vs 64-bit storage), this is especially true for DirectX technologies where most types used are floats (single, 32-bit)